# What component to use to send mail with any kind of body?

Tags: c#, email, sendmail, document-body

I made a mail sender in C# but I'm having trouble with the body of the mail. It only sends the texts without pictures, links and other elements. Not to mention, I used `RichTextBox` for that purpose.

So now my question is: what component to use to send mail with pictures, links and else?

I also enabled `IsBodyHtml` to `true`.

What I want to do is to copy the pictures, links and texts (with different colors and size) from Microsoft Word and paste it to control, and when user gets mail he gets the exact same body and layout as I send them.

Comment: Well you need to construct the HTML, it isn't going to do for it you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to send it as html.
Save your word doc as html and use that.
For the images in your document you can either point to them via their absolute urls (publicly available via the internet).

Or you could use the `LinkedResource` class.

With the LinkedResource class your images have to specify a cid in the source.

```
var inlineLogo = new LinkedResource("path/myfile.png");
                                inlineLogo.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 

var imageHtmlFragment = string.Format("<img alt='My Logo'  src='cid:{0}' style='width: 250px;height: 60px;'/>",inlineLogo.ContentId);

var newMail = new MailMessage();

var view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(imageHtmlFragment, null, "text/html");
                        view.LinkedResources.Add(inlineLogo);
                        newMail.AlternateViews.Add(view);
```